# Facebook URL Need to Run Ads

Tags: facebook

Choose an iTunes App ID: To run this iOS 14 campaign, you need to provide an iTunes app ID and URL. (#2490250)

Been at this problem for 2 months now without a resolution. Please, anyone help.

Integrated with Branch.io and latest Facebook SDK installed. Events set up and registering.